# Why is a bounty fixed in increments?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I currently have 46 reputation points. I have posted a question which I need help with but have yet to receive any answers. The question is clear and concise. I've even posted my entire script to help seek solutions. Why does SO limit the bounty to increments of 50?

It's kinda like having pennies as part of a monetary system when only dollars are accepted in transactions. If someone wants to help me for 46 reputation points, I should be able to award them the 46 reputation points as agreed upon.

Sure, I could go out and try to answer some questions to gain more points, but to be honest, I'm not a computer programmer or scientist so competing with "professionals" on here is not an option. Their "low hanging fruit" is often out of my reach. Now that I think about it (as I'm writing this), I am one of the people who actually provides the "low hanging fruit". The only way I gain reputation points is if I get upvotes on questions.

Now I find myself in a position where I really need help and I'd "pay" for it, but apparently my "money" is no good, unless it comes in the form of "dollars". So again, why limit the bounty offering to fixed increments as opposed to what I choose to offer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation "suggested edit is accepted: +2 (up to +1000 total per user)"

Comment: @ThatsRightJack downvotes on meta indicate disagreement with the suggestion being made, not negative judgement of the quality of the post.

Comment: @Ben What suggestion? Are you implying that if I question SO's philosophy, it gets a down vote?

Comment: @ThatsRightJack the suggestion that it should be possible to set bounty amounts arbitrarily. People will use voting as a mechanism to express agreement or disagreement with this suggestion. This doesn't imply any judgement on you for having made the suggestion, so there's no need to worry 

Comment: @Ben OK...that makes sense. I'm fine if people disagree. I guess it would be good to know why they disagree as opposed to just clicking a button.

Comment: Technically, they just click the button to show their disagreement </pedant>

Comment: We are having some matlab guys look at it, and to improve the question. So hopefully that helps Jack.

Comment: @ThatsRightJack if you find that helpful: I disagree with your proposal (not really sure how it is more useful than downvote :) )

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Because you're not telling me WHY you disagree. It's a discussion provoked with a question. Yes, the button is a good way to measure your vote, but I was not proposing SO change anything. I was simply asking why the bounty is fixed. If people disagree, it would be good to know why, which addresses the question, therefore it is more useful.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Well it seems my tag has been changed from "discussion" to "feature-request". In that case, it sounds more like a poll, so sure, I don't expect everyone to give a response back.

Comment: @ThatsRightJack If you're going to request a feature, then the question ought to be tagged as a feature request.  Mistaking a feature request as a discussion isn't helpful to anyone.

Comment: @Servy My original post was tagged with "discussion" not "feature-request". Someone else changed that. There is no request in my post.

Comment: @ThatsRightJack The fact that you mis-tagged your feature request as a discussion doesn't change the fact that you're requesting a feature.  Just like if you had used the "bug" tag it wouldn't have made this a bug report.

Comment: @Servy I made no such feature-request, nor did I tag it as such. Quote me where I did.

Comment: @Servy:  I'm not convinced that this is a feature request.  It seems to me that it's more of a question trying to gain understanding as to why the system is the way it is and less about trying to change that system.

Comment: @ThatsRightJack Why do you keep asserting that you mis-tagged the question in response to being told that you mis-tagging the question doesn't change what the question is asking?

Comment: @Makotoq He's asserting that he should be able to set a bounty of any amount that he wants.  That's requesting a feature (or a change to an existing one).

Comment: @Servy you're reading way to deep into this

Comment: The truth is, you should *not* have to spend a bounty in order to get your question answered. It is a way to skirt around the normal system, like jumping up and down to get attention instead of waiting your turn. If you ask a clear, answerable, and interesting question, people will answer it, no payment needed. Rather than complaining about why you can't bounty your question, you should be asking about how to improve your question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you post a bounty, you're paying for attention. If you could set bounties with only 1 rep, the "featured" questions section would just be constantly flooded with thousands of posts with 1 rep bounties on them, and as a result, no one would actually be getting any additional attention.

Comment: Alright, I see your point. In order to reward those who help the most (measured via rep points), SO gives them the opportunity to gain more attention when they need it. Makes sense.

Comment: @ThatsRightJack I literally said none of those things.  It takes all of one mediocre post to earn enough for 50 rep to post a bounty.  Having done that doesn't mean you're one of SO's top contributors.